# Is it possible to switch between angular views without reloading in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angualr app with 2 views, the map view (state: app.map) and list view (state: app.list). After the data is loaded, I want to allow the user freely switch between the 2 views without reloading the page (like controller) and the data. Is that possible with ui-router? Thanks

my map is created inside the controller, so every time the controller is re-instantiated, the map is also re created, which is slow. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: yes, One of AngularJS best uses is to create a "Single Page Application" (SPA).

Comment: hi, Noypi. I know that in SPA, the web page themselves are not reloaded. But the controller will be re-executed, right?

Comment: state is probably from a third party which uses angular, but in core angularjs, controllers gets executed / created when used in a route. and all controllers gets instantiated everywhere else.

Comment: you can also instantiate a controller using ng-controller, and there are many ways to instantiate a controller.

Comment: see this example, it shows that controlelr gets instantiated when a route changes... http://ngtutorial.com/learn/route.html#toc_11

Answer (score 0):

Of course, have a look at [their sample app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) :)